# How do I find out the expiry date of a SQL Server 2008 trial-install instance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, installation

So I installed a trial of SQL Server 2008 enterprise edition while waiting for MSDN licenses to come through - I now want to uninstall the trial and replace it with a developer edition installation.

However, I'd like to first know how long I have left on the trial.  Is there a way to do this programmatically with SQL?  I looked at create_date in sys.databases, but these give dates that are in 2003 (which is, I guess, when master and model were originally created).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://mangalpardeshi.blogspot.com/2009/05/expiration-date-of-sql-server.html

Edit: Just spotted you want to do this programatically. Guess you could start a profiler trace then open management studio to see how it gets this info!

Comment: Yeah; been there.  But yes - I want to know if I can do something like select license_expiry from sys.importantserverstuff.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes a 180 Day trial

```
SELECT
@@SERVERNAME SERVERNAME,
CREATE_DATE 'INSTALALTIONDATE',
SERVERPROPERTY('EDITION') 'Version',
DATEADD(DD, 180, CREATE_DATE) AS 'EXPIRY DATE'
FROM SYS.SERVER_PRINCIPALS
WHERE SID = 0X010100000000000512000000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @daysleft int
declare @instancename sysname
select @instancename = CONVERT(sysname, SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceName'))   
exec @daysleft = xp_qv '2715127595', @instancename
select @daysleft 'Number of days left'
GO
```

This should tell you date your Evaluation Period expires.